# Edit and delete forms with angular, javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, function

I wrote a simple code that when implemented will generate elements from the array (bookmarks), and for each element there is Edit & Delete buttons. I wrote the html code that passes the submit to a function called updatebookmark() for the edit, and deleteBookmark() for the delete, but neither buttons give a response back when clicked, this is the link to jsfiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/SaifHarbia/5xds83fn/

The updateBookmark function looks like this(it is supposed to update the under-edit values and directly replace the old values on screen):

```
function updateBookmark(bookmark) { // updating the under-edit bookmark

        var index = _.findIndex($scope.bookmarks, function (b) {
            return b.id == bookmark.id;
        });
        $scope.bookmarks[index] = bookmark;
        $scope.editedBookmark = null;
        $scope.isEditing = false;
    }
```

While the deleteBookmark function looks like this:

```
function deleteBookmark(bookmark) { // delete a bookmark
    var index = $scope.bookmarks.indexOf(bookmark.id);
    _.remove($scope.bookmarks, function (b) {
        return b.id == bookmark.id;

    });
}
```

Comment: @Shaun I can't select correct answers, StackExchange doesn't allow me that as I'm new to the site and don't have enough points :) 
You could of seen the reason before posting your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was issue with your underscore file linking in fiddle. Also remove function was not proper. Check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5xds83fn/1/)

Remove functionality:-

```
function deleteBookmark(bookmark) { // delete a bookmark
        var index = $scope.bookmarks.indexOf(bookmark.id);
      $scope.bookmarks =  _.reject($scope.bookmarks, function (b) {
            return b.id == bookmark.id;

        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much mate !! that solved it.
can you elaborate more on the issue, what was it ?

Comment: Firstly, in the jsfiddle you haven't linked underscore file thus it was giving error. Also in the remove functionality you need to assign the updated bookmark array after deletion which was missing in your code and also _.remove is not a underscore function.

Comment: Sorry I don't know php :( And in fiddle I have linked the underscore file in the external js section, have a look.

Comment: FYI phpStorm is a tool to write JavaScript, xml, html, not only php, anyhow  I figured how to use the library there, I only needed to include the file inside <script> I also did it for jsfiddle, your answer was so helpful, you are awesome !!